# Distinguishing between nearly identical letters. (ㅎ and 종)

Tags: hangul

"ㅎ" is a single letter (hi-eut).

But it is not what appears in "종", where the "ㅗ" and the "ㅇ" are two distinct letters.

Is there something obvious (which I can't see) that distinguishes between the two?

Comment: 종 can’t be ㅈ stacked on top of ㅎ because the combination of two or more basic letters is always either `1. 자음+모음` or `2. 자음+모음+자음` which respresents a single syllable. (자음 = consonant / 모음 = vowel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see the two consonants ㅈ and ㅎ on top of each other, unless someone is playing with fonts, because that's an invalid combination - a valid syllable must contain a vowel.

So 종 can never be ㅈ+ㅎ: it can only be ㅈ+ㅗ+ㅇ.

Comment: So a final "ㅎ" must always be preceded by a vowel and so couldn't be two letters.

Comment: @RayButterworth unless it's a special consonant like ㄶ but you most likely won't mistake them for anything else